# How to find protractor element using [(ngModel)]

Tags: protractor

I have trouble to locate the element using  [(ngModel)]. This is angular2 syntax, I can not find any document for this.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Summary</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="task.summary">
</div>
```

I tried multiple way to locate the elements, e.g.

```
var input = element(by.model('task.summary'));
input.sendKeys('123');
expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe('123');
```

But it failed with error Failed: unknown error: angular is not defined.
And I make it work with the following workaround, but I really want to use [(ngModel)] to locate the element.

```
  var input = element.all(by.css('input'));
  input.sendKeys('summary');
  expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe('summary');
```

Comment: Could you post which protractor version are you using and the contents of the protractor config? Thanks.

Comment: protractor is Version 3.1.1.        config.json is {
  "webdriverVersions": {
    "selenium": "2.52.0",
    "chromedriver": "2.21",
    "iedriver": "2.52.0"
  }
}

Comment: have you tried using by.binding('task.summary')?

Comment: A work around would be to use element(by.css('[[(ngModel)]="task.summary"]'));

Comment: by.binding('task.summary') give me the same error "angular is not defined". by.css('[[(ngModel)]="task.summary"]')  give me "invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified" error. I am using chrome.

Comment: @qunzi how about `element(by.css('[\\[\\(ngModel\\)\\]="task.summary"]'))`?

Comment: I got same problem with `by.model` with Protractor 3.3

Comment: Based on Julia Ralpha air show, looks like Protractor did not support these new angualr 2 directives yet.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. I resolved as below. by.model does not support for  more then Angular 2.0. So, I resolved using by.css properties.

```
element(by.css('[name="firstName"]')).sendKeys('Protector User');
```